# How to write a javascript function inside a string

Tags: javascript, r

I'm trying to run a JavaScript function in R.
One part of the code requires me to pass a JavaScript function containing a filename as a string. Because the string contains a file path this leads to all hell breaking loose with single and double quotes and backslashes. Here is what I have

```
d3chart$chart(tooltipContent = "#! function(item, x, y, e,z){ 
   return '' + '<img src=\"/Users/cBl.png\"' + '/>'
          } !#")
d3chart
```

The result should be that I can see an image in a tooltip on a chart. The whole thing runs without error, but on the chart I get a question mark instead of the image which I guess means it cant follow the filename path. I think this is because I'm not sure how to write this filepath string properly to call the img `src` part.

Comment: If the problem isn't with escaping, it could be the relative URL of the image. Is the `/Users/cB1.png` path in the same directory where the HTML is being generated?

Comment: How do I find out where the html is being generated?

Comment: I ran it in chrome and got Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND so I guess maybe the problem is that the file path itself is incorrect relative to where the html is being generated?

Comment: I used d3chart$chart(tooltipContent = "#! function(item, x, y, e,z){
   return '' + '<img src=\"./cBl.png\"' + '/>'
          } !#")    but no joy

Comment: Try putting an absolute URL to an image like this:   `d3chart$chart(tooltipContent = "#! function(item, x, y, e,z){ return '' + '<img src=\"http://i.stack.imgur.com/BDie5.png"' + '/>' } !#")`. If that loads ok, then it is some kind of file path issue. If not, then it could be an escaping issue.

Comment: OK. It turns out it was a path issue. Using the developer tools in chrome (which are great) I could see that the html was looking for the file in teh working directory of R (oh well thats what you get if you try to run javascript from R). In the end all I needed was to reference the image from the R working directory and then I could use it

Answer (score 0):

I guess its the line break that causing the whole string to be syntax error, also I would remove the return ''+ it has no meaning 
I added the full path to the file location so you will be able to debug in order to get better understanding if that a wrong file location issue

you can add **\n\** to end of line:

```
d3chart$chart(tooltipContent = "#! function(item, x, y, e,z){ \n\
   return '<img src=\"'+document.location.hostname+'/'+document.location.pathname+'/Users/cBl.png\"' + '/>'\n\
          } !#")
d3chart
```

Comment: I still get the same result with this

Comment: can you access this file in full url path? if you can add the full path to the function and make sure you can load it using this function if you cannot access this file you should check what is the http error type it could be many things my guess is permissions

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit hard to know exactly what you're going for since the javascript is kind of messed up but this should work:

```
d3chart$chart(tooltipContent = "#! function(item, x, y, e,z) { return '<img src=\'/Users/cBl.png\' />' } !#")
```

Comment: mostly the problem seems to be misplaced `'` and `"`. Converted it to not use `"` in javascript, but just escapes `\'`.